# Data for <select> dynamic .html jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, select, dynamic, jquery-mobile

I want to add dynamic data to an option menu .
i have used .html(object). 
object has the format
 `'<option>ww</option>....<option>xx</option>'`

Comment: could you please provide more code and describe what the problem is more detailedly?

Comment: ok i receive my data from data base and i convert it to object. After this i want to fill '<select>' by this object.                           My code for fill '<select>' is "$('#description').html(cc); "

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#description').html(cc).trigger('create')
```

or

```
$('#description').html(cc).trigger('refresh')
```

depending on whether or not the element is brand new or not.

See **Enhancing new markup** in http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html